# spring boot autowire runnable class with parameter constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, runnable, executorservice

I have to implemented runnable in a class to create thread. I need to pass data in the thread run method. Initially i setup the data through parameter constructor and pass it with creating class object with new which resulted in null where ever autowired or @value was used(as it was no longer spring managed),I could not autowire the constructor parameters  those are not beans.

Sample code for better understanding :

```
@Controller
public class UrlShortnerThread implements Runnable {

   // My constructor
   public UrlShortnerThread(List<JobsModel> jobsList, DataWriter dataWriter, Marshaller marshaller) {
    this.jobsList = jobsList;
    this.dataWriter = dataWriter;
    this.marshaller = marshaller;
}
```

In other class i autowired

```
@Autowired
UrlShortnerThread urlShortnerThread;
```

and tried to use the run method of urlShortnerThread.

So can i initialise constructor with spring as the parameters of the constructor are not beans.

Hi, because i cannot autowire jobsList(constructor parameter) as it is not available to me during project configuration and the list is created in one of the controllers by getting data from db. All i want is to spllit the list in sublists and pass each sublist to thread to update some contents of the sublists(through an api) and write each sublist in the xml file.

Or is there any better way to do it.

Comment: It is unclear why you can't use constructor parameters, which is the preferred way of autowiring generally.

Comment: Hi, because i cannot autowire jobsList(constructor parameter) as it is not available to me during project configuration and the list is created in one of the controllers by getting data from db. All i want is to spllit the list in sublists and pass each sublist to thread to update some contents of the sublists(through an api)